# config rclone to support diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1

Tags: go, cryptography, sha1, sha256, rclone

Some quick background. I use `rclone` to transfer data to a SFTP server.  rclone is written in Golang and uses lib `crypto` under the hood. When we try to establish ssh connection to SFTP server, we get the error message

> couldn't connect SSH: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithm
>   for key exchange; client offered: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
>   ecdh-sha2-nistp256 ecdh-sha2-nistp384 ecdh-sha2-nistp521
>   diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 diffie-hellman-group1-sha1], server
>   offered: [diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
>   diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1].

`crypto` lib has added the support for `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1` around 3 weeks ago, but needs to be opt-in. (See https://github.com/golang/crypto/commit/57b3e21c3d5606066a87e63cfe07ec6b9f0db000)

Obviously, the latest rclone version hasn’t opt-in those algorithms support yet. So the question is: Anyone know how to config rclone to opt-in algorithm support for `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1`

Comment: https://github.com/ncw/rclone/issues/1810 references this issue.  As you haven't given a complete minimal example showing this problem, I am going to vote to close and suggest you rely on the project's bug tracking

Comment: It's also not a programming question in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have managed to opt-in those algorithms support and submitted a PR here: https://github.com/ncw/rclone/pull/3341

Note: since those algorithms are considered insecure, your also need to use the exisiting rclone flag `--sftp-use-insecure-cipher` to make them available for SSH handshake.

Answer (score 1):

The interactive `rclone config` now provides enabling insecure ciphers as well:

```
Enable the use of insecure ciphers and key exchange methods.

This enables the use of the following insecure ciphers and key exchange methods:

- aes128-cbc
- aes192-cbc
- aes256-cbc
- 3des-cbc
- diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
- diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1

Those algorithms are insecure and may allow plaintext data to be recovered by an attacker.
Enter a boolean value (true or false). Press Enter for the default ("false").
Choose a number from below, or type in your own value
 1 / Use default Cipher list.
   \ "false"
 2 / Enables the use of the aes128-cbc cipher and diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 key exchange.
   \ "true"
use_insecure_cipher> 2
```